# Get component from Array sqlite

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I have array from sqlite like this : `[(1, u'01', u'Data push button1'), (2, u'01', u'Data push button2'), (3, u'01', u'Data push button3')]`

I want to separate id and data from that array like this :`id =[1,2,3]` and `data =[Data push button1,Data push button2,Data push button3]`

Any idea how I can do this?
I do this in python 2.7 and this is my python code :

```
import sqlite3

tablename='vcsdata'

conn = sqlite3.connect('vcsdb2.db')
cur= conn.cursor()

def insert (cmd_type, data, create_time, status):
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO '+tablename+' (cmd_type, data, create_time,status)VALUES (?,?,?,?)',\
                (cmd_type, data, create_time, status))

insert ('01','Data push button1','2015-11-11',1)
insert ('01','Data push button2','2015-11-11',1)
insert ('01','Data push button3','2015-11-11',1)
insert ('01','Data push button4','2015-11-11',0)
insert ('01','Data push button5','2015-11-11',0)

cur.execute('SELECT id,cmd_type,data from vcsdata WHERE status = 1')
data=cur.fetchall()
```

I don't want to change my sqlite prgram I only want extract my list. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the data you need after SQL SELECT in `fetched` list.

```
fetched = [(1, u'01', u'Data push button1'),
    (2, u'01', u'Data push button2'), 
    (3, u'01', u'Data push button3')]
```

You can extract your `id` and `data` by using list comprehension:

```
id = [x[0] for x in fetched]
data = [x[2] for x in fetched]
```

This will go through your `fetched` list twice, you may want to use a `for` loop if your `fetched` list is really large.

Or you can use one list comprehension instead:

```
id = []
data = []
[(id.append(x[0]), data.append(x[2])) for x in fetched]
```

Comment: Thankyou @Rikka. Can you help me how to get every size of data? data = 17Data push button1, 17Data push button2, 17Data push button3. I want get size every data.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by `size of data`? Can you explain your problem in another question?